# Basic boolean logic in a MySQl query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, having-clause

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1007f82c715b9015529ca6ef5f94b15) for details.

Basically, I am searching a very basic test database for jobs with one of 3 companies: BAe, Thales & Google.

The database looks like this when shown in tabular form (full details of the structure are in the fiddle):

```
Candidate name  Company Job year    Skills
One             Thales  2015        C
One             BAe     2016        Python
One             Google  2017        C++
Two             BAe     2015        C++
Two             Google  2020        Python
Two             Thales  2019        C++, UML
Three           Google  2019        Python
```

I am trying various queries to find who has worked at which companies (the skills are not relevant to this question).

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidate_id FROM jobs j
WHERE 1=1
AND ( EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM companies c
             WHERE c.company_id = j.company_id
             AND UPPER(c.company_name) LIKE 'THALES'));
```

correctly gives:

```
+--------------+
| candidate_id |
+--------------+
|            1 |
|            3 |
+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidate_id FROM jobs j 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM companies c 
             WHERE c.company_id = j.company_id 
             AND UPPER(c.company_name) LIKE 'GOOGLE'));
```

correctly gives

```
+--------------+
| candidate_id |
+--------------+
|            1 |
|            2 |
+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT, when I try to combine, to find a candidate who has worked at both Thales and Google, I expect to get candidate 1, but instead I get an empty result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidate_id FROM jobs j 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( EXISTS ( 
             SELECT * FROM companies c 
             WHERE c.company_id = j.company_id 
             AND UPPER(c.company_name) LIKE 'THALES') 
 AND  EXISTS ( 
             SELECT * FROM companies c 
             WHERE c.company_id = j.company_id 
             AND UPPER(c.company_name) LIKE 'GOOGLE') 
);

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What is wrong with the last query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching the `jobs` table, and thus you are looking for jobs both at Thales and Google, and then are selecting all distinct candidates for those jobs.

Since a job (in your datamodel) is only at one company, no job can match, and thus no candidates are returned.

The below query will give what you want:

```sql
select * from candidates c
where 1=1
and ( exists (
  select * from jobs j
  where j.candidate_id = c.candidate_id
  and (exists (select * from companies com where com.company_id = j.company_id and upper(com.company_name) like 'THALES'))
))
and ( exists (
  select * from jobs j
  where j.candidate_id = c.candidate_id
  and (exists (select * from companies com where com.company_id = j.company_id and upper(com.company_name) like 'GOOGLE'))
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this is an aggregation query with filtering in the `HAVING` clause.

```
select candidate_id
from jobs j
inner join companies c on c.company_id = j.company_id
where c.company_name in ('Thales', 'Google')        -- either one or the other
group by candidate_id
having min(j.company_id) <> max(j.company_id)       -- both match
```

In [your db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c525cb096dfa408bb69a307964a34485), this produces:

```
| candidate_id |
| -----------: |
|            1 |
```